# How can i extend Users table of ASP.Net 4 membership

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-membership, asp.net-4.0

I want to extend the users table of ASP.Net 4 memberships as below picture

[image]

So when the user register on the website i can control the extra columns ("WaitingApprovalRevenue", "ApprovedRevenue" and "WithdrawnRevenue")

Or i should play with default asp.net users table ?!!

Comment: Use a [`Profile`-provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/014bec1k(v=vs.100).aspx) instead. On this way you can provide additional properties for a user of any type(f.e. an  image for an avatar).

Comment: I have this exact same question. Can you just extend the tables with additional columns without breaking the Membership system? I would logically think you could, as all of the data it needs is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Profile` provider, but there is a drawback to the default ASP.NET one where it basically stores all the values in a single field. This makes it hard when you have something outside of the ASP.NET environment which needs to use those values (eg. for reporting purposes).

If that's not a problem, use `Profile` as Tim has linked, otherwise I would create a separate table with the user GUID as a key and just link it that way.